# How to maintain scroll position after client-side validation fails?

Tags: asp.net, scroll, validation

I've got an ASP.NET webform with `asp:TextBox` and `asp:RequiredFieldValidator` at the bottom of the page. If client side validation fails on form submit - the page scrolls all the way up.

I'd like to maintain the scroll position on failed client-side validation.

I've found [this solution](http://www.aghausman.net/dotnet/maintain-scroll-position-with-aspnet-validation-controls.html), but it seems overly complex.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach I've found, after looking at this pretty deeply, is to put your error messages at the top of the page in a Summary.

Comment: weird, once i moved the validation summary to the top - scroll position stopped resetting. I have no idea why this happened - but thanks nevertheless.

Answer (score 14):

I was a bit stuck with this problem. This seemed to fix the problem for me.

I fixed it by adding this to the OnClientClick event of the input button.

```
onClientClick="window.scrollTo = function(x,y) { return true; };"
```

Have a look at here for more analysis.
http://blog.waiholiu.info/2011/04/how-to-maintain-scroll-position-of-page.html